# Как изменить версию PHP для одного сайта на базе IIS7 (Windows Server 2008 R2)?

Tags: php, iis

Всем привет.
Есть сервер на базе IIS7. На нём работают несколько сайтов. Версия PHP 5.4.45 стоит на всех сайтах.
Мне нужно изменить версию PHP на одном сайте на PHP 7.2.0
Делаю следующую процедуру:

1. Скачиваю архив php-7.2.0-nts-Win32-VC15-x64.zip
2. Распаковываю содержимое в C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\php 7.2.0
3. Изменяю в php.ini следующие пункты:

   fastcgi.impersonate = 1
   cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1
   cgi.force_redirect = 0
   open_basedir = "D:\sites"

extension_dir = "C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\php 7.2.0\ext"
4. Открываю IIS Manager, выбираю сайт (на котором нужно изменить версию PHP), выбираю пункт Handler Mappings
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
5. Редактирую модуль PHP_via_FastCGI таким образом:
Request path: * .php
Module: FastCgiModule
Executable : «"C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\php 7.2.0\php-cgi.exe"»
Name: PHP_via_FastCGI
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
6. Запускаю info.php
В поле Loaded Configuration File прописан всё тот же путь к старой PHP (C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\php.ini)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Насколько я понимаю не подключаются расширения mysql, mysqli, pdo_mysql

Файл applicationHost.config содержит такие строки:

```
<fastCgi>
        <application fullPath="C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\php-cgi.exe" activityTimeout="600" requestTimeout="600" instanceMaxRequests="10000">
            <environmentVariables>
                <environmentVariable name="PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS" value="10000" />
                <environmentVariable name="PHPRC" value="C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\" />
            </environmentVariables>
        </application>
        <application fullPath="C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\php 5.5.30\php-cgi.exe" />
        <application fullPath="C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\php 7.4.13\php-cgi.exe" />
        <application fullPath="C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\php 5.6.9\php-cgi.exe" />
        <application fullPath="C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\php 5.6.21\php-cgi.exe" />
        <application fullPath="C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\php 7.2.0\php-cgi.exe" />
    </fastCgi>
```

Что я делаю не так?
Почему не подключаются extensions?

Comment: расширения `mysql` для 7.х нет в принципе. а указанное надо раскомментировать в конфиге. зы: вообще есть оснастка а-ля "администратор пхп" для iis

Comment: дальше то поищите pdo на странице